# Como controlo um video pela Scroll?

Tags: javascript, html5

gostaria de saber como posso controlar um video pela scroll usando Javascript ou alguma outra técnica.

Grato

Ex: Scrolling controls for HTML5 video

http://codepen.io/ollieRogers/details/lfeLc

Comment: O Codepen desse Ollie Rogers funciona bem, exceto pela falha em detectar corretamente (pelo menos no meu Chrome + Ubuntu) quando a rolagem começou. O que você gostaria que fosse diferente desse exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deixo aqui uma explicação do que está a acontecer no codePen que indicou.

```
// selecionar o elemento do video
var vid = document.getElementById('v0');
//var vid = $('#v0')[0]; // variante com jQuery

// pausar o video ao inicio
vid.pause();
 
// pausar o video ao detectar um scroll (para impedir auto-play)
window.onscroll = function(){
    vid.pause();
};

// procurar, a cada 40 milisegundos, o scroll atual da página e mostrar a frame com esse numero/400
setInterval(function(){
    vid.currentTime = window.pageYOffset/400;
}, 40);
```

Se quiser mudar um pouco o código dê uma olhada a esta variante:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Lm6/

```
var vid = document.getElementById('v0');
vid.pause();
window.onscroll = function () {
    vid.currentTime = window.pageYOffset / 400;
    vid.pause();
};

document.getElementById('play').onclick = function () {
    vid.play();
}
document.getElementById('pause').onclick = function () {
    vid.pause();
    window.scrollTo(0, vid.currentTime * 400); // para colocar o scroll no sitio quando faz pause
}
```

Aqui juntei dentro do scroll a parte que estava com o setInterval e juntei um botão `play` e `pause` para exemplificar como pode controlar o video.

Answer (score -2):

```
window.onscroll = function() {
myFunction()};
var video = document.getElementById('videotrailer');

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 350) {
    this.video.pause();
  }
   else{
    this.video.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Explique um pouco seu código e não só cole ele aqui.